# WCF with SSL doesn't use any certifacte and fails

Tags: wcf, ssl, ssl-certificate, webmatrix-2

I have created a WCF with several calls and I want to protect it with Transport security so it'll go over SSL.

So I configured SSL in webmatrix since I'm using VS2012 + IIS Express like you can see below.
[image: HTTPs configured in Webmatrix on port 44330]
*HTTPs configured in Webmatrix on port **44330**.*

I updated my Web.config to support one endpoint with metadata on HTTPS and transportsecurity.

```
<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Counter" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
    <endpoint address="https://localhost:44330/Counter.svc"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="HTTPsBinding"
              contract="ICounter">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="HTTPsBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behavior">
      <serviceMetadata
            httpGetEnabled="false"
            httpsGetEnabled="true"
            httpsGetUrl="" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Now when I run this in the browser it points me to the metadata at the HTTPS address like you can see below.
[image: HTTP works but HTTPs fails]
*HTTP works but HTTPs fails.*

And here is the problem, it doesn't use any certificate and I don't see anything.
[image: "This page can't be displayed" without any certificate being used.]
*"This page can't be displayed" **without** any certificate being used.*

How do I fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered adding the mexHttpsBinding endpoint

Comment: Have you considered mapping a certificate to the port 44330. You could do this in 2 ways. One via IIS and the other using netsh command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it that my issue wasn't located in my WCF configuration since it worked the day before. After a lot of coffee, surfing and command lining I noticed that the issue was IIS Express and it's SSL bindings with `netsh http ssl`.

I was using the default IIS Express certificate (CN=localhost) because I didn't include any serviceCertificate like Sam Vanhoutte suggests.
Even when specify a certificate IIS Express only uses **CN=localhost** that needs to be in **LocalMachine > Personal** when starting IIS Express.

If that doesn't fix your problem, try to reinstall IIS Express.
(It will reinstall the CN=localhost certificate on the correct place - Don't forget to reenable SSL in Webmatrix)

Comment: Seems like IIS always takes the localhost certificate since it's running on localhost:44330 is guess.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to specify your server certificate in your web.config

```
<behaviors>
  <behavior name="wsHttpCertificateBehavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
    <serviceCredentials>
      <clientCertificate>
        <authentication 
          certificateValidationMode="PeerOrChainTrust" 
          revocationMode="NoCheck"/>
      </clientCertificate>
      <serverCertificate findValue="CN=SSLCert"/>
    </serviceCredentials>
  </behavior>
</behaviors>
```